# Go-Back-N Protocol not efficient?

Tags: computer-networks, tcp

Let's say we have five packets

> p1 p2 p3 p4 p5

to be sent sequentially:

and for some reasons, p3 got delayed so it the the last packet to arrive recevier.

so below is the receiving order on the receiver's end

> p1 p2 p4 p5 p3

and according to the Go-Back-N Protocol, the receiver will only send acknowledge of `p2` when it receive `p5`.

then the receiver receives `p3` right after `p5`, and then it sends acknowledge of `p3` to the sender.

But there will still be a timeout and the sender still has to re-send `p4` and `p5`,even though the receiver did receive all packets, isn't this Go-Back-N Protocol really inefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go-Back-N protocol is often presented for didactic purposes as a first, maybe crude attempt at tackling loss of packets or of order in connection-oriented communications, without obeying the constrains of [Stop-and-Wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop-and-wait_ARQ) protocols, also introduced for didactic purposes.  It is no wonder it appears inefficient -- it probably was never meant to be so.  [Selective Repeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_Repeat_ARQ) can be considered as a performance improvement in terms of retransmissions over Go-Back-N, and in practice TCP itself relies on a hybrid solution of the two.